# Parsing Doxygen XML and Generating .docx Files

Tags: python, lxml, doxygen, python-docx

I have been automating my C code with Doxygen for a long time, and find the HTML output great for understanding the code.  However, I have a new requirement to generate Word .docx files containing the same information, but with very particular formatting requirements.

Using the python-docx package, writing a .docx file, and configuring the styles to match my requirements is pretty straightforward, parsing Doxygen's XML outputs with LXML.  However, for the more complex fields (e.g. detailed description of files and functions), there is fairly complex document-style XML markup.

My understanding is there can be an arbitrary nesting of `<para>`, `<itemizedlist>`, `<xrefsect>` and other tags with free-standing text "tails" trailing them at the same level.  My approach to converting from nested XML to flat .docx paragraphs and bulleted lists has been to employ a state-machine, but this seems fragile since there could be an arbitrary number of nesting levels.

My current strategy is [in a gist here](https://gist.github.com/superlou/6990947).  I was wondering if there is a more general way of understanding documents with complex nesting. Is there a less fragile tactic than my state-machine?  I'm not sure if I'm trying to reinvent the wheel, but the more cases I add to the state-machine, the less it feels like a robust solution.